# Is there a way to make a time series out of an unevenly intervaled data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I have a data set with paired values which I have converted into a data frame like this:

```
(50.0, 0.0), (49, 27.891), (48, 28.119), 
(47, 28.146), (46, 28.158), (45, 28.195), 
(44, 28.261), (43, 28.274), (42, 28.316), 
(41, 28.326), (40, 28.608), (39, 28.687), 
(38, 28.736), (37, 28.746)

numeric_data
   clean_time_numeric clean_position_numeric
1               0.000                     50
2              27.891                     49
3              28.119                     48
4              28.146                     47
5              28.158                     46
```

This data frame has time points and the position of a slider at that time point. I want to make a time series with intervals of 0.001 with the corresponding position of the slider in the next column, so the position would be 50 until the 27,891st row.

I have tried this piece of code with the `xts` and `zoo` packages that I saw from another post:

```
df1.zoo <- zoo(clean_time_numeric)
df2 <- as.data.frame(as.zoo(merge(as.xts(df1.zoo), as.xts(zoo(,seq(start(df1.zoo[1]),end(df1.zoo[89]), order.by = as.POSIXct.numeric(clean_time_numeric, tryformats = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")))))))
```

but this error keeps showing up:

```
Error in xts(coredata(x), order.by = order.by, frequency = frequency,  : 
  order.by requires an appropriate time-based object
```

I am new to coding in R so I'm not really sure how to approach this or if there's an easier way to solve this, any suggestions are welcome!

Thank you,

Edit: I also tried this:

```
numeric_data$clean_time_numeric<- as.POSIXct.numeric(numeric_data$clean_time_numeric, tz= "GMT", origin = "1970-01-01", tryformats = "%H:%M:%S")

tseries <- data.frame(x = seq(head(numeric_data$clean_time_numeric,1),tail(numeric_data$clean_time_numeric,1),by = "sec"))

res <-merge(tseries, numeric_data, by.x="x",by.y="clean_time_numeric",all.x = TRUE)

xts(res$clean_position_numeric,order.by = res$x)
```

With this, only the first data point is correct - the rest are NA and it stops way before the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

1. create a sequence with 0.001 interval
2. join this sequence to the original dataframe
3. use `zoo::na.locf` to replace NA by last known value

```
df <- read.table(text = "
          clean_time_numeric clean_position_numeric
               0.000                     50
              27.891                     49
              28.119                     48
              28.146                     47
              28.158                     46",header=T)

time.001 <- data.frame(time = seq(min(df$clean_time_numeric), max(df$clean_time_numeric), by =0.001))

library(dplyr)
df.001 <- dplyr::full_join(df, time.001, by = c("clean_time_numeric"="time")) %>% 
       arrange(clean_time_numeric) %>%
       mutate(clean_position_numeric = zoo::na.locf(clean_position_numeric))

head(df.001)
  clean_time_numeric clean_position_numeric
1              0.000                     50
2              0.001                     50
3              0.002                     50
4              0.003                     50
5              0.004                     50
6              0.005                     50

tail(df.001)
      clean_time_numeric clean_position_numeric
28155             28.153                     47
28156             28.154                     47
28157             28.155                     47
28158             28.156                     47
28159             28.157                     47
28160             28.158                     46
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `numeric_data` data frame shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, convert it to a zoo series using `read.zoo`.  Then set its frequency to 1000 (this is the number of points per unit interval),  convert to ts class and use `na.locf0` (or `na.approx` for linear interpolation or `na.spline` for spline interpolation) to fill in the NAs that were created by the conversion from zoo to ts.

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(numeric_data)
frequency(z) <- 1000
tt <- na.locf0(as.ts(z))

length(tt)
## [1] 28159
deltat(tt)
## [1] 0.001
range(time(tt))
## [1]  0.000 28.158
```

We can now

1. leave it as a ts object, `tt`, or
2. convert it to a zoo series: `as.zoo(tt)`, or
3. convert it to a data frame: `fortify.zoo(tt)`

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
numeric_data <- 
structure(list(clean_time_numeric = c(0, 27.891, 28.119, 28.146, 
28.158), clean_position_numeric = 50:46), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```